# Google Chrome shows no text/fonts when opened with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So i was using some python scripts  for automating some stuff in google chrome. Since yesterday i experience a really strange bug. When i use 
the script to open Google Chrome via selenium, all Websites look like this:
Screenshot

[image]

I blurred out the faces, they get displayed perfectly. But there is absolutely no text getting displayed, not even in console. This worked for 
weeks now and all of the sudden it looks like this.

Any Ideas how to fix it?
I tried reinstalling Chrome and chromedriver, without success.

Comment: I just found out that the scripts still work if i execute them in the IDLE Shell. So the problem is most likely the terminal right?

Comment: Same problem here. I've also tried reinstalling literally everything (node, selenium, webdriver), but no luck either.

Comment: Changed system and chrome language to English solve the same problem.

Comment: That worked for me too @kapa89, thank you!

Comment: Changing system language worked for me too. Thanks @kapa89!

Comment: yep, did its thing for me too, thanks a lot @kapa89

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.25 (Build officiel) beta (64 bits) fixed my problem

Comment: As per [Google Chrome version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) **Chrome 68.0.3440** still in **Current Beta channel**. yet to be **GA**. Be catious

Answer (score 1):

Change your system language to English to solve this problem

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to why this would solve this issue. Single liners are not really very helpful in solving the questions.

Answer (score 0):

have a look if the `disable-gpu` comand line flag for chrome helps you

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/183#issuecomment-401820926