# Chrome 67doesn't display text while driven by Codeception

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I run Crome while run Codeception tests and I get Chrome without text everywhere.
It began after updating Chrome to version 67.0.3396.87.
New cromedriver (2.40) and selenium_server (3.12) doesn't solve this problem

[image: No text in Chrome 67]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome shows no text/fonts when opened with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855640/google-chrome-shows-no-text-fonts-when-opened-with-selenium)

Comment: @yunandtidus thanks. Updating to version 68 helps me